# Comment utiliser un acronyme anglais dans un texte en francais ?

Tags: orthographe

Dans le domaine scientifique, la plupart des papiers publiés sont en anglais.

Dans ma thèse, que j'écris en francais, je parle d'un algorithme qui s'appelle en anglais **Differenciated square root cubature Kalman filter** dont l'acronyme anglais est **DSCKF**. Dans le texte j'ai écrit cette phrase :

> par la suite j'utiliserai l'acronyme anglais  DSCKF  pour  Differenciated square root cubature Kalman filter.

Est-elle correcte ?

Comment: As a side remark I think you'll need to plan quite some time for proofreading and correcting your thesis as this simple question was full of tiny mistakes which certainly didn't make it impossible to understand, but still.

Comment: Si je ne me trompe pas à la fin d'une thèse il y a également une partie décrivant les acronymes, pense juste à rajouter cette définition à ce moment-là.
Sinon j'aurai ajouté "DSCKF pour parler de l'algorithme Differenciated ..."

Comment: Notez que "DSCKF" n'est pas un acronyme (un acronyme étant un sigle composé d'initiales ou de syllabes, mais prononcé comme un seul mot et non lettre par lettre. Ex: ONU, PACS, etc.). Erreur très courante, mais qui ferait tâche dans une thèse...

Answer (score 1):

Comme le fait remarquer user **Greg** dans un [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40598/comment-utiliser-un-acronyme-anglais-dans-un-texte-en-francais/40599#comment81755_40598) on ne doit pas appeler *DSCKF* un acronyme ; le terme correct est « sigle » ([réf.](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-22948.php)).

Cette phrase me semble assez correcte excepté en ce qui concerne deux  détails, le manque de précision de « par la suite » et le défaut d'utilisation de guillemets et/ou de l'italique; il me semble que la formulation correcte serait la suivante.

- [dans ce qui va suivre]/[dans les explications]/[…] j'utiliserai le sigle anglais *DSCKF* pour *Differenciated square root cubature Kalman filter*.

ou

- [dans ce qui va suivre]/[dans les explications]/[…] j'utiliserai le sigle anglais « DSCKF » pour « Differenciated square root cubature Kalman filter ».

*D'autres expressions pourront convenir mieux que « [dans ce qui va suivre]/[dans les explications] » mais seul l'auteur peut décider celle qui pour lui est préférable.*

1/ « Par la suite » signifie « ensuite, plus tard » ; si on introduit l'idée de postériorité à quelque chose il faut que ce quelque chose soit mentionné et il n'existe très possiblement pas de contexte pour cela dans le contexte où se trouve la phrase.  Si le terme doit être utilisé de façon consistante dans la plupart du texte, l'idée de cet état de chose (qui fait défaut à la locution « par la suite ») peut être rendue par "dans tout le texte/traitement" ; si ce n'est pas le cas et que le sigle n'est utilisé que dans une partie du texte on peut  peut être préciser cela par "dans une partie du texte".

2/  Dans les combinaisons de termes où le second est un cas particulier d'une espèce nommée par le premier, sauf exception, le second est entre guillemets. Voir [ceci](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect7&info0=7.3).

> Mots se désignant eux-mêmes
>
> On peut aussi recourir à l’italique pour cette fonction : c’est un point sur lequel l’usage varie beaucoup (voir 5.3.6 Mots se désignant eux-mêmes). Il en va de même des appellations de nature diverse introduites par des verbes comme appeler ou nommer :

- le terme « alinéa »
- le terme « alinéa de rattrapage » est inconnu.

*Exceptions*    Par exemple les noms d'œuvres ne prennent pas de guillemets et on utilise de l'italique dans le texte imprimé.

- Le livre *Les Misérables* a été écrit par Victor Hugo.

« Differenciated square root cubature Kalman filter » est un tout et en plus c'est de l'anglais, donc l'italique s'impose, mais les guillemets sont une option acceptable. Voir « Langues étrangères » dans la [réf.](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect7&info0=7.3) ci-dessus.

Après avoir introduit le sigle, en italiques, il devrait quand même rester en italique dans le reste du texte si c'est le sigle d'un terme dans une autre langue.